# HTTP redirect does not work after cookie

Tags: perl, http, redirect, cookies, header

Using Perl with [`CGI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) and [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session)

```
 $session = CGI::Session->load();
 $session->header(-cookie => $cookie, @_);
```

then after the above:

```
 $q = new CGI;
 $q->redirect('url.com');
```

The redirect won't work this way, is there a solution? I don't want to use an HTML `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` element

Comment: Please elaborate. What does *"The redirect won't work"* mean? Does *"does not work after cookie"* mean that everyting is fine without the `$session->header` statement? I think you need to show the context wherein you're calling `$q->redirect`

Comment: 1) It doesn't happen. 2) The purpose of that call is to send a session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

You are outputting two headers.

Solution:

Instruct $session->header to output the correct header.

```
$session->header( -status => '302 Found', -location => $url );
```

---

- `$session->header` is a shortcut for:

  ```
  my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new( -name => $session->name, -value => $session->id );
  print $cgi->header( -cookie => $cookie, @_ );
  ```
- `$cgi->redirect($url)` is a shortcut for:

  ```
  $cgi->header( -status => '302 Found', -location => $url );
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, now you can use `$session->redirect`...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw/ dd /;
use CGI::Session;
sub CGI::Session::redirect {
    my $self = shift;
    my( @args ) = 1==@_ ? (  -uri => @_ ) : @_;
    return $self->query->redirect(-cookie => $self->cookie, @args );
}

dd( CGI::Session->new->redirect );
dd( CGI::Session->new->redirect( 'http://blah' ) );
dd( CGI::Session->new->redirect( -status => '307 Temporary Redirect' ) );
__END__
"Status: 302 Found\r\nSet-Cookie: CGISESSID=ca91ba2e503366755dfad156fc2c3db8; path=/\r\nDate: Sat, 18 Apr 2015 01:15:49 GMT\r\nLocation: http://localhost\r\n\r\n"
"Status: 302 Found\r\nSet-Cookie: CGISESSID=be18ccf65a3cfaa4997b7047d662a825; path=/\r\nDate: Sat, 18 Apr 2015 01:15:49 GMT\r\nLocation: http://blah\r\n\r\n"
"Status: 307 Temporary Redirect\r\nSet-Cookie: CGISESSID=ae059a7d25d0932077035bbc108784f2; path=/\r\nDate: Sat, 18 Apr 2015 01:15:49 GMT\r\nLocation: http://localhost\r\n\r\n"
```

Comment: Why create the sub in CGI::Session's namespace?

Comment: for convenience and because CGI::Session should provide this convenience :)

Comment: That's a reason not to do it. Cause if it starts, you could end up with hard to debug problems. There is absolutely no good reason to do it the way you did, and many bad ones. The question was rhetorical; it was identifying a problem needing fixing in your answer.

Comment: Besides, CGI::Session already does make it quite convenient, as I showed in my answer

Comment: you should probably just mention that you're being rhetorical next time

Comment: I was giving you the benefit of the doubt

Comment: why? if all you want to say is "monkeypatch bad" you can lead with that, I won't mind :)

Comment: Monkeypatching has uses

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet works for me :

```
use CGI;
$cgi = CGI->new();
$cookie = $cgi->cookie (
  -name => $name,
  -value => $value,
  -expires => yadda, yadda
);    
print $cgi->redirect ( -cookie => $cookie, -uri => $redirect_page );
```

YMMV